# Swift 3.2 iOS -How to Increment a NSNumber for Firebase MutableData Object?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, increment, nsnumber

In Swift I understand NSNumbers are containers that contain scalar numbers.

InFirebase you can send NSNumbers to the database but not Ints.

I'm using Firebase Transactions for a number of likes/upvotes and I need to increase the number of times a user presses the upvote button.

Here's my code to send the data to Firebase:

```
likesRef?.runTransactionBlock({
       (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in

       var value = currentData.value as? NSNumber

       if value == nil{
           value = 0
       }

       let one: NSNumber = 1

       currentData.value = value! += one //error is here

       return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
```

I keep getting error:

> Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to two 'NSNumber' operands

[image]

The problem is I'm passing a `Firebase MutableData` type to the `success(withValue: )` method and not the NSNumber value itself. I can't use `NSNumber.intValue` because Firebase doesn't accept Ints.

**How can I increment two NSNumbers together to send to to Firebase as part of a MutableData object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
let newValue: Int

if let existingValue = (currentData.value as? NSNumber)?.intValue {
    newValue = existingValue + 1
} else {
    newValue = 1
}

currentData.value = NSNumber(value: newValue)
```

Comment: thanks, I’ll try it in a couple of hours or so and get back to you

Comment: I kept getting an error on the second line before the opening curly brace **(currentData.value as? NSNumber)?.value**. The error was **"Ambiguous use of 'value"**. I used **(currentData.value as? NSNumber)?.intValue** instead and it worked. I'm using Swift 3.2, you might have to update it for that by switching **.value** for **.intValue**. Other then that your answer works great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use UInt instead of Int. This works for me:

```
.runTransactionBlock { (currentData) -> TransactionResult in

        if var value = currentData.value as? UInt {
            value += 1
            currentData.value = value
        } else {
            currentData.value = UInt(1)
        }

        return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
    }
}
```